# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when moving app from local machine to remote server

Tags: node.js, web-services, web-applications

Had a look around at some other threads and there doesn't seem to be someone with this exact problem.

The problem is that I have made a webapp that works fine when hosting it locally. On the app there is a button that causes a request to be sent to my server and it performs as expected on localhost:3000 but when I host it remotely on a linux box purchased from digital ocean the site loads but the when the button is pressed I see

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

in the console.

I'm not sure how useful it would be to post code so I will leave that out unless requested. I'm hoping this is due to some server configuration issue?

Further info:

This is a node application on a server running ubuntu. To run the application I use and keep it running I use PM2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the function on that button logically?

Comment: @reds It simply encrypts an API call that a user enters into an input and sends it off to my server. Server decrypts it, sends the request in it's original form and sends the response it receives from the third party API back to my frontend.